# Telegraf callback_query

Tags: node.js, telegraf

Help me correctly handle a callback request from a button in the bot. I cant find how to do that and have problem

```
bot.hears('Contact', async (ctx) => {
    try {
        await ctx.replyWithHTML('<b>?</b>', Markup.inlineKeyboard(
            [
                [Markup.button.callback('kyky', 'kyky')], 
                [Markup.button.callback('mymy', 'mymy')]
            ]
        ))
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
})

bot.on('callback_query', query => {
    console.log(query)
    const chatId = query.from.id
    if (query.data == 'kyky') {
        bot.sendMessage('@kyky')
    }
    if (query.data == 'mymy') {
        bot.sendMessage('@mymy')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this

```
bot.hears("Contact", (ctx) => {
  ctx.reply("<b>?</b>", {
    parse_mode: "HTML",
    ...Markup.inlineKeyboard([
      Markup.button.callback("kyky", "kyky"),
      Markup.button.callback("mymy", "mymy")
    ])
  });
});

bot.action("kyky", (ctx) => {
  ctx.reply("@kyky")
})

bot.action("mymy", (ctx) => {
  ctx.reply("@mymy")
})
```

`bot.action` listens for an `inline_keyboard` callback and `bot.hears` listens for `keyboard` callback, so I assume there is a message that looks like this for the `bot.hears` method to listen to when Contact button is clicked

```
ctx.reply("some message", {
  ...Markup.keyboard([
    Markup.button.callback("Contact")
  ])
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The document here is very clear about this https://github.com/feathers-studio/telegraf-docs/blob/master/examples/keyboard-bot.ts

We use the `action` to handle it.

```
import { Telegraf, Markup } from "telegraf";

const bot = new Telegraf(token);

bot.command("random", ctx => {
    return ctx.reply(
        "random example",
        Markup.inlineKeyboard([
            Markup.button.callback("Coke", "Coke"),
            Markup.button.callback("Dr Pepper", "Dr Pepper", Math.random() > 0.5),
            Markup.button.callback("Pepsi", "Pepsi"),
        ]),
    );
});

bot.action("Dr Pepper", (ctx, next) => {
    return ctx.reply("").then(() => next());
});
```

And don't forget to set the `callback_query` to the `allowUpdates`. Otherwise the `action` won't work

```
bot.launch({
  allowedUpdates: ['message', 'callback_query'],
});
```